# Define on $P3$ the inner product $<f,g>=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)dt$, find orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials, projection-matrices

Define on $P3$ the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)dt$.

a) find the orthogonal projection of $p(x)=x^3$ onto $P2$

I know the orthogonal projection formula, but how do I solve it without knowing $f(t)$ and $g(t)$?

I also have a hard time in turns of proving the Positive Definite Property of this inner product.

Comment: I think you should say what are $P3,P2$.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are just there to define the inner product.

Comment: will be i using the orthogonal projection formula here?

Comment: I suppose $P_n=\mathbb R_n[X]$. You have to verify the given product is an inner product, then find an orthonormal basis for $P_2$ (by Gram-Schmidt for example), then use your projection formula.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS do u might showing me how to use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis?

Comment: is integral from -1 to 1 or from 1 to -1 in the definition of inner product?

Comment: @mathnoob sorry i made a mistake, it's from -1 to1

Comment: A standard basis $B$ for $P_2$ is $\{1,x,x^2\}$. We get a orthogonal basis by Gram-Schmidt.

$u_1=x^2$,

$u_2=x-\frac{\langle x^2,x \rangle}{\langle x^2,x^2 \rangle}x^2 =x-0=x$

$u_3=1-\frac{\langle x^2,1 \rangle}{\langle x^2,x^2 \rangle}x^2-\frac{\langle x,1 \rangle}{\langle x,x \rangle}x=1-\frac{5}{3}x^2$


So now, $B_1=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ form an orthogonal basis for $P_2$.

Comment: @mathnoob i was using $u_1$=$1$ and it came up to be different basis from yours.